# Numerically order SPARQL results that are external identifiers but actually all numbers

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I wrote this query to list Wikidata items that have an [RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) identifier:

```
SELECT ?rfcId ?itemLabel ?classLabel ?item
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 ?class.
  ?item wdt:P892 ?rfcId.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ?rfcId
```

A minor problem is that they are sorted in an alphabetic way: 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 101, etc.

I tried using `ORDER BY xsd:nonNegativeInteger(?rfcId)` but it does not work, probably because [the property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P892) is defined as an "external identifier" rather than as a number.

Can I modify the query to sort results in numeric order (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,etc)?

Comment: Try `ORDER BY xsd:integer(?rfcId)`.

Comment: Tried this and it appears to work: http://tinyurl.com/yazaeneq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tipped by Stanislav Kralin and Barry Carter, `ORDER BY xsd:integer(` is the solution:

```
SELECT ?rfcId ?itemLabel ?classLabel ?item
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 ?class.
  ?item wdt:P892 ?rfcId.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY xsd:integer(?rfcId)
```

https://tinyurl.com/yazaeneq

Comment: BTW, there are HTML, TXT and XML indexes: https://www.rfc-editor.org/

Comment: pinging you for this thread https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/413/1511